# Need Help to display array values into blade using @foreach with relationship models

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox, foreach, relation

I have 4 types of subscriptions(monthly, 3 months, 6 months and yearly). I successfully inserted the value with relation to my product model. Now I need to make an update. Scenario is the user choose only two subscription plan at the beginning then decided to add more subscription. In my edit It only display what the user selected.

```
 @foreach($product->subscriptions as $subscription)

 <input class="form-check-input" name="availability[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $row->id }}" checked>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked"><b>{{ $subscription->name }}</b></label>

 <input type="text" name="price[]" value="{{ $subscription->pivot->price }}">

 @endforeach
```

This will give result: How can I display also the other options that not selected before. 
     [image]

I want to display the rest of the subscription availability unchecked if the result is less than 4. For example, the user chooses only monthly and yearly. Now in my edit view, I want to display also the other two (3 months and 6 months options) in case they want to add something. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach($subscriptions as $subscription)

   <input class="form-check-input" name="availability[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $row->id }}" {{in_array($subscription->id, $product->subscriptions->pluck('id')) ? 'checked' : ''}}>
   <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked"><b>{{ $subscription->name }}</b></label>

   <input type="text" name="price[]" value="{{ $subscription->pivot->price }}">

 @endforeach
```

Comment: this gives me Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance